# How to embed HTML url pages in adobe flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a desktop adobe `flex` application and would like to show the content of an `URL`. How could a `HTML` page be best embedded into a desktop flex app?

I know there is some old `mx:HTML location="{url}"` but this seems to have many rendering and javascript issues.

I don't want to open an external browser window.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `StageWebView` with argument `useNative=true`. [Here is a wrapper component for Flex.](http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2011/01/16/stagewebview-uicomponent/)

Comment: This answer is dependent on AIR being the target platform. Since there is no mention of using AIR in the question, you may want to point that out.  Also, make it a good answer by adding an example, instead of just a one liner with a link.

Comment: @Batman Actually, he did mention "desktop adobe flex app" which implicates use of AIR, and the `HTML` class which is already an AIR class. Code example isn't very helpful in this case because there's no specific code question he's asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stagewebview for rendering html page in flex application. Use below code to open google page.

**Note:** 'http' or protocol of the url should be added in the url.

```
        private var _stageWebView:StageWebView;
        private var _stage : Stage;

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            _stage = this.stage;
        }

        private function onInitStageWebView():void
        {
            _stageWebView = new StageWebView(true); //true - for system engine, false - embedded webkit
        _stageWebView.stage = _stage1;
        _stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(42, 50, this.width, this.height);
        _stageWebView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        _stageWebView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
        _stageWebView.addEventListener( LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onLocationChange_Handler );
        _stageWebView.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
        }

       protected function onLocationChange_Handler( event : LocationChangeEvent ):void
       {
           trace( "Location Changed to : " : event.location );
       }
```